# How to create responsive using iframes in html

Tags: html, css, iframe, overflow, responsiveness

I have created a page which contains 15% space for header and 10% for nav bar and remaining space for iframe. In iframe the displaying of main content will be done.

So coming to my problem how to acquire responsiveness of the website, when i zoom in all the contents just come out of its allocated container. Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider taking a [tour], reading [ask], and updating your post with a [mre] of your code. We're here to troubleshoot code and we can't see yours! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.